# In C, when might the names "forgiveme" and "forgivemenot" refer to the same variable?

Tags: c, variable-declaration

[This](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/declaring-variables-in-c.html) website says that "Don't give similar names to your variables. For example, the compiler may assume that `forgiveme` and `forgivemenot` are the same variable. If so, an ugly situation can occur."

I have never read of this problem in variable naming. When will such an ugly situation be most likely to occur? And what do they mean by saying that the compiler **may** assume that they are not the same variable?

Comment: Not sure I would trust advice from some source that includes the word 'Dummies' ;)

Comment: @jpw It's for dummies, not necessarily by dummies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Names should be unique in their first 31 characters

§5.2.4.1 Translation limits of the C11 standard says

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one
>   program that contains at least one instance of every one of the
>   following limits:18)
>
> — 31 signiﬁcant initial characters in an
>   external identiﬁer (each universal character name specifying a short
>   identiﬁer of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each 18)
>   Implementations should avoid imposing ﬁxed translation limits whenever
>   possible.

The same limit applies for C99 so your example names should be uniquely identified by any standards-compliant compiler from the last 10+ years.

Comment: There are standards, and then there's the real world everyone else lives in where they sometimes have to work with systems that don't adhere to the latest greatest standard. While the standard is certainly true, it remains that there **are** compilers out there where variable name length matters. That's the only caveat I would add... for all practical purposes, according to the standard, variable name length should not be an issue... however, there are exceptions one should be aware of.

Comment: I don't doubt there are non-compliant compilers out there.  Do you have any particular examples in mind?

Comment: I haven't done embedded stuff in quite a while, but I've seen no shortage of standards violations in compilers for micro-controllers/embedded systems over the years. I'm not calling out any in particular, but that's the place where one most often sees "liberties" taken.

Comment: The K&R compiler only saved 8 characters for external names, and one of those was always a leading underscore. I once contributed a program to usenet that would convert a set of C files with conflicting names into one without.

Comment: Whoa, a reference to it (shortc) still exists: http://books.google.com/books?id=vweTteq3OLQC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=shortc+long+identifiers&source=bl&ots=BBb3hDWyYn&sig=HH5bExtR0SsR-VOVjhVVKM3luhA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fiHbU5TzJIW70QXvgoDABA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=shortc%20long%20identifiers&f=false

Answer (score 5):

The C (from 1999) standard says in `5.2.4.1 Translation limits`:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
> — 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier ...

And then in `6.4.2 Identifiers / 6.4.2.1 General`:

> As discussed in 5.2.4.1, an implementation may limit the number of significant initial characters in an identifier; ...
>
> Any identifiers that differ in a significant character are different identifiers. If two identifiers differ only in nonsignificant characters, the behavior is undefined.

So, `forgiveme` and `forgivemenot` being considered the same if there are less than `10` significant characters supported is a nice undefined behavior.

`31` is what used to be `6` in the C standard from 1989 (AKA ANSI C).

Answer (score 4):

There was a time, a very long time ago, when the maximum length of a symbol was eight characters. You could use a symbol longer than eight, but only the first eight were significant.

That time passed somewhere in the '80s.

Comment: In 7th Edition UNIX™ (1978), the C compiler was limited: _2.2 Identifiers (Names)
An identifier is a sequence of letters and digits; the first character must be alphabetic. The underscore `_` counts
as alphabetic. Upper and lower case letters are considered different. No more than the first eight characters are significant,
and only the first seven for external identifiers._

Answer (score 3):

There was a time, and there were (are) compilers that limit the length of a variable name. If, for example, the compiler in question only allows 8 character variable names, then in fact this would be a problem as both `forgiveme` and `forgivemenot` would be the same variable `forgivem`

However, most modern compilers this is a non-issue. If you are working with an arcane compiler, or a small embedded systems compiler that has issues with variable name length, then this could be a problem.